# 2 datasource connection using properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connection, datasource

My application.yml file looks something like:

```
spring:
profiles: environment

jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: none
datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://myUrl
  username: master
  driver-class-name: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
```

My DatabaseConnection class looks something like:

```
@Component
public class DatabaseManager {

public static final String CONTEXT_KEY = "context";
public static final String CONTEXT_VALUE = "myContext";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "my-credential-store";
public static final String CREDENTIAL = "mydb.password";
public static final String WRITE_ENDPOINT_OUTPUT = "mydbwriteendpoint";
public static final String DATASOURCE_URL = "spring.datasource.url";
public static final String DATASOURCE_PASSWORD = "spring.datasource.password";

public static void createConnection() throws Exception {
    JCredStash jCredStash = null;

    try {
        Map<String, String> context = new HashMap<>();

        context.put(CONTEXT_KEY, CONTEXT_VALUE);
        jCredStash = new JCredStash(TABLE_NAME);

        String secret = jCredStash.getSecret(CREDENTIAL, context);
        String writeEndpoint = jCredStash.getSecret(WRITE_ENDPOINT_OUTPUT, context);

        System.setProperty(DATASOURCE_URL,
                "jdbc:mysql://" + writeEndpoint + ":port/mydb");

        System.setProperty(DATASOURCE_PASSWORD, secret);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (jCredStash != null)
            jCredStash.close();
    } 
  }
}
```

Here, I am getting the DB password from AWS Cred Stash. Everything is working fine for "mydb" database. Now I have created another database named "mydb1" inside the same URL instance with the same username and password. I have tried a couple of options like creating another data source, but nope of them worked for me. Can anyone guide me how can I create the connection with "mydb1" along with "mydb"? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect to `mydb1` using any SQL client? If not then the issue is in how you created set up that new database. If you are able to connect then the issue is in your config file

Comment: I am able to connect to mydb1 using the config file but then mydb doesn't connect. I am asking how can I establish a connection with both the database simultaneously.

Comment: You have a static method that sets system properties with connection properties. This will not work in case of several data sources. And usually with Spring you do not need static methods to init connection. These links provide examples on how to set up several datasources using Spring Boot: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/multiple-data-sources-with-spring-boot/, https://springframework.guru/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-in-a-spring-boot-application/